# Anaconda Selenium issues with webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, geckodriver

I have been struggling to figure out why I keep getting errors trying to use selenium. I'm using a local install of anaconda3 on my /home/user unix drive at the company I work for. I already pip installed selenium, seemingly without issue, but when I try the following:

```
 from selenium import webdriver
 driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

it fails with the following message:

```
WebDriverException: Message: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line
```

I've tried downloading the most current chromedriver and trying with that, I've tried installing another gecko-driver, I've tried all kinds of things. But nothing is working. I'm happy to provide any amount of additional information, I just want to get this off the ground at some point...

Thank you!

Comment: On which path is firefox installed?

Comment: It's just whatever is installed by my company, sitting on my C: drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from selenium import webdriver

path = r'C:\yourgeckodriverpath\geckodriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, through a combination of the responses to this question, I have figured out what (I think) went wrong. I was using a linux anaconda install on my company's servers, which (I believe) meant my python had no access to a browser driver. The solution was sadly to install anaconda locally, manually download/unzip/install selenium and geckodriver, and then make sure I pass the whole "executable_path=path" parameter to the Firefox method. This didn't work for Chrome for some reason, which I'll assume has something to do with the unchangeable security specifications on my work machine. If any part of this doesn't sound right, feel free to chime in and shed more light on the issue. Thanks!